# Telerik grid insert update using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

In the below code i have radgrid i want to insert, delete, update in the grid. But i don't know whether to get the values and place the code because i am new to telerik controls.

ASP:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server"   AllowPaging="True" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" AllowAutomaticInserts="True"
        AllowAutomaticDeletes="true" AllowSorting="true" OnItemCreated="RadGrid1_ItemCreated"
        OnItemInserted="RadGrid1_ItemInserted" OnPreRender="RadGrid1_PreRender"  >
            <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
        <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="EmployeeTypeID" CommandItemDisplay="Top">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn">
                </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="EmployeeTypeID" HeaderText="EmployeeTypeID" SortExpression="EmployeeTypeID"
                    UniqueName="EmployeeTypeID" Visible="false" >
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="EmployeeType" HeaderText="EmployeeType" SortExpression="EmployeeType"
                    UniqueName="EmployeeType">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CostPerDay" HeaderText="CostPerDay" SortExpression="CostPerDay"
                    UniqueName="CostPerDay">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="WorkingHours" HeaderText="WorkingHours" SortExpression="WorkingHours"
                    UniqueName="WorkingHours">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                <telerik:GridButtonColumn Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" ButtonType="ImageButton" />
            </Columns>
            <EditFormSettings>
                <EditColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />
            </EditFormSettings>
        </MasterTableView>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

C#

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCreated(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
            {
                if (!(e.Item is GridEditFormInsertItem))
                {
                    GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
                    GridEditManager manager = item.EditManager;
                    GridTextBoxColumnEditor editor = manager.GetColumnEditor("EmployeeTypeID") as GridTextBoxColumnEditor;
                    editor.TextBoxControl.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
        protected void RadGrid1_ItemInserted(object source, GridInsertedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Exception != null)
            {

                e.ExceptionHandled = true;
                SetMessage("Employee cannot be inserted. Reason: " + e.Exception.Message);

            }
            else
            {
                SetMessage("New Employee is inserted!");
            }
        }
        private void DisplayMessage(string text)
        {
            RadGrid1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format("<span style='color:red'>{0}</span>", text)));
        }

        private void SetMessage(string message)
        {
            gridMessage = message;
        }

        private string gridMessage = null;

        protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(gridMessage))
            {
                DisplayMessage(gridMessage);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly what your problem is.  Are you not seeing the edit fields? Is the delete button not showing up?

Comment: @paqogomez yes ic an see edit and delete but i don't know where to place edit code and delete code in code behind

Answer (score 1):

You have the insert command handler in your ASPX, but you are missing the delete handler.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" 
                 runat="server"   
                 AllowPaging="True" 
                 OnDeleteCommand="RadGrid1_DeleteCommand"
                 ...
```

The insertions and deletions to your grid happen automatically, but they dont happen automatically in your database.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemInserted(object source, GridInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    //...ADD CODE TO INSERT TO YOUR DB HERE!
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {
     ...
```

[Telerik's edit examples](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/automatic-crud-operations/defaultcs.aspx)

```
protected void RadGrid1_DeleteCommand(object source, GridInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    //...ADD CODE TO DELETE FROM YOUR DB HERE!
    ...
```

[Telerik's deleting example](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-how-to-delete-a-record.html)

Dont forget to rebind the grid to see the results.  `RadGrid1.DataBind();`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to define the update/delete/insert operations in the datasource (e.g., SqlDataSource control, it has the appropriate SQL commands as properties and they can have parameters) and use the built-in CRUD operations: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/automatic-crud-operations/defaultcs.aspx